# What does one mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does one mean in this context?

> We have travel brochures for ten different destinations
>
> Feel free to take **one**

Does it mean:

- You can take one brochure
- You can take as many brochures as you want of one type
- You can take as many brochures as you want of all types

Comment: You would have to ask a person who works there, as the notice is ambiguous. In addition to your three suggested meanings, it might mean "you can take one brochure for each of the ten different destinations".

Comment: What people mean and what they write are frequently differenr. I suggest that Mr. Harvey's suggestion is what is meant. My wife had surgery on her wrist. Her discharge instructions told her what not to do with her "operative" arm rather than what not to do with her injured arm. A law suit waiting to happen.

Comment: I'd be inclined to suspect it's "as many brochures as you want of any combination of types", but written with the expectation that few if any readers will *want* more than one of any given type.

Comment: "Take one" is commonly used to indicate that the item is free. It does not specify the qty. you can take.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literally it means "take one brochure". In practice it almost certainly means "take one of each that you are interested in". Though they might take a dim view of someone claiming to be interested in every single different brochure that they have.